# Remove suggestions and auto complete in wkwebview

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, wkwebview

i'm working on a mac os text editor. Sometimes when i try to fill the contents an autosuggestion pop up and fills.... how can i remove it in wk webview
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `autocorrect="off"` to the `input` or `textarea` element. WkWebView seems to want to make these suggestions/corrections by default now, where even Safari doesn't.

I think this must have started happening in an update because our app using WkWebView on Mac didn't previously do this.

Comment: I tried autocorrect="off" on textarea in WKWebView but the suggestion still shows? Did you find the solution to this problem on iPhone? Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm it fixed it for Mac, but we're not using WkWebView on iOS so I can't confirm for that platform.